# How do I get correct exposure for long shutter times in bulb mode?

Tags: exposure, long-exposure, bulb-mode

How do I take a very long exposure shot from EOS M? I see when i reduce the shutter speed to bulb setting, i see the picture is completely over exposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "exposure triangle"?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle)

Comment: Triangles still have nothing to do with it. :-/

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "very long", [How do I meter for long exposures (10+ minutes)?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/how-do-i-meter-for-long-exposures-10-minutes) may cover your question.

Comment: Are you shooting in the daytime or at night?

Answer (score 3):

Bulb mode allows you to control when the exposure starts and finishes, which means that you control the shutter-speed. Together with ISO and Aperture, you still need to balance the 3 parameters and get a proper exposure. See [Exposure Triangle](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle) if you are not familiar with the concept.

To be clear, you do not *reduce the shutter-speed to bulb*. You *take control of shutter-speed with bulb*.

Now you have to use choose a shutter-speed. The easiest way is to get the camera to meter and then balance with other exposure parameters. Usually, I take a shot in Aperture priority mode at a ridiculous ISO, say 25600. If it comes out exposed properly, note the shutter-speed and then calculate how long it would take at a low ISO, say 200. You can work this out in your head but you don't have to anymore, as they say *there's an app for that*. The one I use simply called *Exposure Calculator*.

The other option is to meter at the desired ISO with a set aperture again and note the shutter-speed. Then, add an ND filter, do the math to adjust the shutter-speed. Again, *there is an app for that*. The one I use is called *ND Filter Calculator*. For ND filters, the math is very simple. ND4 == 2 ^ 4 == 16, so multiply the shutter-speed without the ND filter by 16.

Some cameras show a counter on the screen or on the top LCD. *If* that is not the case with the EOS M, use a watch which shows seconds. You should really not have to worry about fractions since it is hard to react with accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't exactly clear on your objective, so I will provide a few potential solutions.

Use your cameras histogram to judge the exposure. See: [How and why do you use an image histogram?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-and-why-do-you-use-an-image-histogram)

Calculate the proper exposure. See: [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle) or [Long Exposure Tutorial](http://bulbexposures.com/free-long-exposure-tutorial/)

Use a neutral density filter. See: [What are neutral density filters and how do I use them to create long exposures in daylight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures)

Or you could simply lower your ISO and use a smaller aperture if you aren't already at the limits of what your camera can do.

Comment: Maybe add [Is it possible to take a long exposure photograph during daytime?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/)