# Area focusing using manual focus

Tags: manual-focus

how to achieve area focus using manual focus mode.
I tried using the infinity, but that did not turn out to be correct for me.

I use a Nikon D3200. When I need all the subjects in focus, I put the camera in Area focus mode. But when I am trying to achieve the same using manual focus. I am not able to do so.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "put the camera in Area focus mode"? Also, I suggest reading the [D3200 User Guide](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/20/D3200.html) to understand the camera's controls and terminology.

Comment: related: [Using one focus point in autofocus mode - interval timer shooting - NIkon d7000](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/how-do-i-meter-for-long-exposures-10-minutes)

Comment: [What does infinity focus mean and when should I use it?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39244/what-does-infinity-focus-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: An example of the consequences of totally misunderstanding the meaning of *infinity focus*: [Why are my pictures blurry even though a DOF calculator shows everything should be in focus?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85589/why-are-my-pictures-blurry-even-though-a-dof-calculator-shows-everything-should)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you need to learn about [depth of field](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9624/what-exactly-determines-depth-of-field).

This is controlling aperture and using that to control how much is in (relative) focus.  It's an important photographic technique.